# How to find a row in a DataGridView by its first column value efficiently

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need a method that prints all weeks in a month from monday to friday, and then print rows in a datagridview that correspond to each working day.

I have a full working solution, but it's not efficient, since i have to look at each row one by one to see if it matches, for each working day in a month:

```
for (int i=diaInicio;i<=diaFinal;i++)
{
    fecha = i.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + "-" + fechaInicio.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') 
                + "-" + fechaInicio.Year.ToString();
    fechaCiclo = new DateTime(fechaInicio.Year, fechaInicio.Month, i);
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgActividades.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(fecha))
        {
            //suppose this actually prints the row's cells
            printRowCells();
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Substring(0, 2)) > i)
        { 
            //break when the grid date is newer that what i want
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

So what this does, is to iterate from the first row to the one which its first column reads november 6th then breaks, then it gets called from november 9 to the 13th and so on... As you see, i have to read up to 31 days for each day in the outer for, which is about 20 times... Almost O(N)^2

Is there some index or map method to position myself right at the first row i need, and then break like what i am doing or will it be too much trouble?

EDIT: it's a little hackish, but if i add a global variable that stores the current position of the DataGridView's index starting from 0, i can effectively iterate through all of it just once:

```
int indiceFila = 0;
for (int i=diaInicio;i<=diaFinal;i++)
{
    fecha = i.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + "-" + fechaInicio.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') 
    + "-" + fechaInicio.Year.ToString();
    while(indiceFila<dgActividades.Rows.Count-1)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dgActividades.Rows[indiceFila];
        if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(fecha))
        {
            printValues();
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Substring(0, 2)) > i)
        { 
            break;
        }
        indiceFila++;
    }
}
```

Of course this only works if the first column is sorted by ascending date

Comment: FWIW this wouldn't be O(n^2), it's n*m, where m is a presumably small constant (you say about 20) which means it's O(n)...

Comment: when m is almost n it would be almost O(n^2) like i said :)